# Why am I getting 'IOError Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' When saving file with PIL

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, ioerror

I am building a site using Django/Python and there is one page where the user can upload a photo which is then re-sized and saved using the following function:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile

def resize(file_to_resize, string_id,):
    parser = ImageFile.Parser()
    while True:
        s = file_to_resize.read(1024)
        if not s:
            break
        parser.feed(s)
    image = parser.close()
    ms = image.copy()
    size = 320,240
    ms.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    ms.save('http://www.mysite.com/site_media/images/profile/' + string_id, "JPEG") `
```

This worked fine while running locally, but once I uploaded the site to my host and ran it under Apache, I got the following error:

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:     http://www.mysite.com/saveimage/8/
Django Version:     1.2.1
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'http://www.mysite.com/site_media/images/profile/8'
Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in save, line 1299
Python Executable:     /usr/languages/python/2.6/bin/python
Python Version:     2.6.6

Also, I am new to web development and Django/Python, this is actually a project I am working on the learn and plan on sharing it with friends and family, so I'm not sure if this is even the best approach when it comes to security and allowing a file to be written directly to the site.  Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no directory called "http:" in the current directory.

If you're *actually* trying to save a file over HTTP, this is not how.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are right, I changed the line to: ms.save('site_media/images/profile/' + string_id, "JPEG") 
and it worked.